# Data not passing into actionresult method in my mvc4 controller from a jquery ajax call

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When sending a json object from jquery to my controller the data is passed into the method, but for some reason is null. Also I cannot seem to post the data without getting a 404 I am forced to use the get method.

My Javascript and jquery call looks like this:

```
var searchQuery = {

    'scope': 'global',
    'query': s
};
console.log(searchQuery);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Search/SearchSite",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: searchQuery,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        $("#pageContent").html(msg);
    }
});
```

My controller looks like this:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult SearchSite(MyQuery query)
{
    string sendBack = "info to send:" + query.query;
    return Content(sendBack);
}
```

My class looks like this:

```
public class MyQuery
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the scope of the search Global etc.
    /// </summary>
    public string scope { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the search query
    /// </summary>
    public string query { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried everything simplifying, and just sending a string in, but that also gets nullified for some reason.

Comment: The `s` you are passing as `query`, is that a variable or you are testing with a hard-coded string 's'?

Comment: Can you post what your `console.log(searchQuery);` returns?

Comment: query: "this is what i typed"
scope: "global"

Comment: That is inside of an object passed into the console

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict between the parameter in your Action Method and one of the MyQuery properties: they are both named "query".  If you rename one of them, your code works.

```
public virtual ActionResult SearchSite(MyQuery myQuery)
{
     string sendBack = "info to send: " + myQuery.query;
     return Content(sendBack); 
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but it still doesn't pass anything through.